# 2020: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1Al.jpg). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Amateur Radio over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 1 | 5 |
| Users destroyed³ | 58 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 2 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 1 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 28 | 74 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 2 | 7 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 12 | 37 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 1 | 105 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 9 | 372 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 9 | 93 |
| Tags merged | 2 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 6 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 6 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 10 | 0 |
| Questions protected | 0 | 4 |
| Questions migrated | 10 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 2 | 63 |
| Questions closed | 74 | 4 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 30 | 35 |
| Posts unlocked | 2 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 10 | 19 |
| Posts locked | 1 | 25 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 101 | 159 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 46 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 46 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 3 | 14 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 377 | 363 |
| Comment flags handled | 15 | 2 |
| Answers flagged | 44 | 138 |
| Answer flags handled | 167 | 13 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 17 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2019: a year in moderation](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518)

A big thank you to [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.

Wishing everyone a happy 2021!

Comment: Thank you for all the moderators putting hard work into this exchange.  It makes the Amateur Radio community better!

Comment: Thanks to everyone! You’ll see that the Community column has generally higher numbers than the Moderators column. This site is mostly moderated by the users of the site. Moderators usually only step in in the cases where the community can’t (e.g. destroyed users, converting answers to comments, tidying up comments when no longer needed)

Comment: Comment moved to [answer](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/a/435/8717).

Comment: JNat, I didn't mean to dump on you in our first interaction. I know you are one of the hard-working CMs here. :-) But would it be possible to edit the column so that it shows only what the human participants did? Or else add a second column for that?

Answer (score 0):

> "... the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks."

**Not so!**

These figures don't tell the whole story. Moderators do much more than the regular users on this site. **And look at footnote 1:** *it puts human participants and the automated systems together!*

The reason why we moderators hesitate to use flags is because mod flags initiate immediate action. (We three mods have discussed this flaw amongst ourselves and feel that this needs to be changed, but that's OT here.)

In fact, I have been discussing the need to educate the community to flag and cast votes on posts (among other things), as *A Theory of Moderation* and the updated version outlines.

Comment: Few folks look at [Ham Shack](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack), but I started [this discussion there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56509297#56509297) anyway. We will move forward with educating the regular users after we get another moderator.

Comment: I was scratching my head about a few actions by the "Community" in the list, like five suspended users.  I'm pretty sure that regular users can't suspend other users, so those five must have been suspended by user #-1.

Comment: @rclocher3 Same goes for other things in this list, which only moderators can see (probably). For example, I can't tell you how many notices I've seen created by user #-1 to the effect that *'This question/answer was flagged as low quality due to its content'*. Some were valid, but others were valid answers. They were all one sentence and one paragraph, which leads one to the conclusion that all answers consisting of a single sentence are flagged. My point is, most of these flags were **not** raised by regular users.

Comment: Making this split is a bit tricky, and entails a non-trivial amount of work — sometimes we attribute certain actions to the community user when in fact they were carried out by multiple users, for instance. As such, I can't guarantee we'll be able to make this change to how we present 2020's stats, but I'll make a note so we can try to take this into consideration in 2021's.

Comment: The table in the question didn't give totals, so I did the math.  Moderators did 1,047 actions, and "Community" did 1,578.